# разметка Layout с рекламой

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Просьба помочь с разметкой. Смысл такой, нужно чтобы внизу `Layout` был банер рекламы, а над ним был `RecyclerView`. Пока добился "почти" приемлемого для меня результата таким вот образом:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_theme_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Просьба подсказать более оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно проще + вы неправильно вес используете - при его назначении надо обнулять соответствующее измерение вьюхи + вес нужен только одному элементу в данном случае. К тому же у вас зачем-то обеим вьюхам (в т.ч. баннеру) назначена высота во весь экран. Вот так попробуйте:

Контейнер высотой во весь экран, баннер во всю нужную ему высоту для отображения содержимого и RecuclerView на всё оставшееся место

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_theme_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, так гораздо лучше!